# Is it possible to have a data structure that is able to store different types?

Tags: java

A single data structure to store different types in a single variable.

Not asking for generics, some a dynamically typed data structure.

Is it possible?

Comment: David's answer below is your only option if Java is your only choice. If not, you might want to look into either Groovy or Scala.

Comment: There is no dynamic typing in Java, as it is a hard-typed language.  The best you can hope for is using an element as an Object, or using generics if the type is known ahead of time.  As mentioned by Chintan, you would need to use a softly-typed language if you wanted that capability.

Comment: Could you add what the issue is that you are trying to address by storing different types in a single variable? That might get you an answer on how to do it 'the java way'. If all the types need to be treated in the same way you need an interface, otherwise just using an object might work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you are asking, but all Java collections support un-typed data. For example:

```
List dataStructure = new LinkedList();

dataStructure.add(new Long(5));
dataStructure.add("Hello");
dataStructure.add(new BankAccount());
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  All the data structures in the standard library end up using generics with type-erasure.  Something like:

```
ArrayList<Object> dynamicData = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

should do just fine.  Just remember, you will have to cast after you pull objects out of the structure.

Comment: How about just plain ArrayList?

Comment: Checkers: Raw types are bad, m'kay. David: Type erasure is completely irrelevant here.

Comment: The compiler complains if you use the bare type and useing List<Object> keeps it happy.

Comment: @Tom It's not irrelevant, but I haven't justified mentioning it.  It's relevant because the data-structures are implemented without reference to the generic type, i.e. it was my way of pointing out that the OP's goal is accomplished by simply telling the compiler to permit anything.  It's not an important or necessary point, just interesting.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use Object as the variable type.

Not sure exactly what you are after. I'd argue that, in Java, it's Generics that provide dynamic typing.

Answer (score 2):

Technically since everything inherits from Object, coupled with autoboxing for primitives yes you can. Although without casts and heavy use of "if X instanceof Y" statements, you'll have a sticky time.

Comment: Actually you'll have a sticky time *because* of casts and instanceof calls :P